# How to make a database field read-only in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a database table with a certain field which should be impossible to update once it has been inserted to the database. How do I tell my model that it shouldn't allow updating of a certain field?

Comment: For clarity, I'd suggest adding " after insert" to the question, as it sounds like you do not want the field to be read-only before insert into the database.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You want to use [`attr_readonly`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_readonly):

> Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but update operations will ignore these fields.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_readonly :your_field_name
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to your question, but "correct" solution to your actual problem is a bit different... see the comment on the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my related solution to a similar problem - we have fields that we want a user to be able to set themselves, we don't require them on creation of the record, but we do NOT want to them be changed once they are set.

```rb
  validate :forbid_changing_some_field, on: :update

  def forbid_changing_some_field
    return unless some_field_changed?
    return if some_field_was.nil?

    self.some_field = some_field_was
    errors.add(:some_field, 'can not be changed!')
  end
```

The thing that surprised me, though, was that `update_attribute` still works, it bypasses the validations.  Not a huge deal, since updates to the record are mass assigned in practice - but I called that out in the tests to make it clear.  Here's some tests for it.

```rb
    describe 'forbids changing some field once set' do
      let(:initial_some_field) { 'initial some field value' }
      it 'defaults as nil' do
        expect(record.some_field).to be nil
      end

      it 'can be set' do
        expect {
          record.update_attribute(:some_field, initial_some_field)
        }.to change {
          record.some_field
        }.from(nil).to(initial_some_field)
      end

      context 'once it is set' do
        before do
          record.update_attribute(:some_field, initial_some_field)
        end

        it 'makes the record invalid if changed' do
          record.some_field = 'new value'
          expect(record).not_to be_valid
        end

        it 'does not change in mass update' do
          expect {
            record.update_attributes(some_field: 'new value')
          }.not_to change {
            record.some_field
          }.from(initial_some_field)
        end

        it 'DOES change in update_attribute!! (skips validations' do
          expect {
            record.update_attribute(:some_field, 'other new value')
          }.to change {
            record.some_field
          }.from(initial_some_field).to('other new value')
        end
      end
    end
```