# Don't allow a user to change email address using devise with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using `devise` to allow users to log in to a site. The authentication key is set to a username, which is to be unique. Also to be unique is the email address provided. It seems that somehow `devise` has already figured out that the email address should be unique. So that's good.

Now I want to let people change their passwords. I link over to my `edit_user_registration_path`, but notice that the user is allowed to change their email address. One option is to set `reconfirmable` to `false`... but I don't think I want to allow users to change their email addresses at all.

I think I could just remove the field from the `devise` view, but theoretically a carefully crafted `PUT` method could still let them change their email address. Is there a way to stop this field from being mutable? Or is it better to just let the email address be reconfirmable?

Comment: may help this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542524/how-to-make-a-database-field-readonly-in-rails

Comment: That is helpful. As I mentioned in the other answer, I kind of expected `devise` to deal with this directly (so that the editing box for the email address doesn't appear at all) rather than manually setting it up myself. I was sure that I missed some simple configuration somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the "answer" was to simply allow people to edit their email addresses. There are enough use cases in which somebody could legitimately want to change their email address that I figured there was no harm in trying to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://trak3r.blogspot.com/2007/03/immutable-activerecord-attributes.html

So

```
class User
  def email=(address)
    if new_record?
      write_attribute(:email, address)
    else
      raise 'email is immutable!'
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Interesting. While this will definitely stop the address from being changed, I was hoping for something within `devise`. That way, the generated view doesn't include an editable text box with something immutable within it. That being said, I think this will work if I just remove that box from the view and use this code...

Comment: Yeah you'll have to edit the view. I could be wrong, but I really doubt Devise has anything built in for this, since this has nothing to do with authentication, and should be more of an ActiveRecord feature than anything else.